# MYSQL string to check against multiple fields

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to check that a similar entry doesn't exist in my database based on four pieces of information before inserting a new row. It's ok if the same name exists for example, but not if Name, Lat/Long,, and time are all the same. Here is my code:

```
$query3 = "INSERT INTO locations
(
Name,
Time,
Area,
Latitude,
Longitude,
Current,
Previous,
Destination
)
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT Name, Time, Area, Latitude, Longitude, Current, Previous, Destination) AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT  Name, Latitude, Longitude, Time FROM
    locations
    WHERE Name = '$Name' AND Latitude = '$latitude' AND Longitude = '$longitude' AND Time = '$timereceived')
";
```

The error that I am pulling currently is

```
Could not connect: Unknown column 'Name' in 'field list'
```

I don't understand the error message, and I'm thinking I have a syntax error in my MYSQL string. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: `echo` your query and test it in your server, it will give you an idea you are executing. Or post the result query to give us more information

Comment: I guess the problem comes from the backticks in your where condition like Latitude = \`$latitude\`, as these are used to describe the column names or table names

Comment: `SELECT '$Name', '$timereceived', '$area', '$latitude', '$longitude', '$currentport', '$previousport', '$destination'` why are you using variables here? Don't you know the name of your fields?

Comment: When I use a fieldname here Name for example, I get this error:
    Could not connect: Unknown column 'Name' in 'field list'
When I remove the ticks from the first column ($name) only, I get
    Could not connect: Unknown column 'Ocean' in 'field list'
Ocean is something that would come from the Name column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is completely messed up.
You are using single quotes for column names and somewhere using backticks for the values and somewhere using variables in the column name

As in your query you have used

```
$Name, $timereceived, $area, $latitude, $longitude, $currentport, $previousport, $destination
```

I guess these variables are holding column names if not use the column name directly in the query

It should look like

```
$query3 = "INSERT INTO locations 
(
Name, 
Time, 
Area, 
Latitude, 
Longitude, 
Current, 
Previous, 
Destination
)
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT $Name, $timereceived, $area, $latitude, $longitude, $currentport, $previousport, $destination) AS tmp
    WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT  Name, Latitude, Longitude, Time FROM 
        locations
        WHERE Name = '$Name' AND Latitude = '$latitude' AND Longitude = '$longitude' AND Time = '$timereceived')
";
```

**UPDATE** 
The query is not correct and missing alias here is one query which should work

```
INSERT INTO locations 
( 
  Name, 
  Time, 
  Area, 
  Latitude, 
  Longitude, 
  Current, 
  Previous, 
  Destination 
) 
SELECT * FROM 
( 
  SELECT 
  Name, 
  Time, 
  Area, 
  Latitude, 
  Longitude, 
  Current, 
  Previous, 
  Destination
  from locations 
)l1
WHERE 
NOT EXISTS 
( 
  SELECT 
  1 
  FROM locations l2
  WHERE 
  l2.Name = 'Ocean' 
  AND l2.Latitude = '145.717' 
  AND l2.Longitude = '-16.6365' 
  AND l2.Time = '2014-04-23 13:45'
);
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2d831c/1)**

**UPDATE2**
Howard Krause has some issues of adding data multiple times so the fix he applied as

```
INSERT INTO locations 
(Name, Area, Latitude, Longitude, Current, Previous, Destination, Time) 
SELECT a.Name, a.Area, a.Latitude, a.Longitude, a.Current, a.Previous, a.Destination, a.Time 
FROM ( 
SELECT  Name, Area, Latitude, Longitude, Current, Previous,  Destination, Time) a 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
SELECT 1 FROM locations WHERE Name= '$Name' AND Longitude = '$longitude'
);
```

Comment: This looks great, but I'm still getting:

    Could not connect: Unknown column 'Name' in 'field list'

To verify, Name is a valid column name in locations table

Comment: can you echo the query to your script and post it on the question after you have all variables set , just `echo $query3`

Comment: INSERT INTO locations
(
Name,
Time,
Area,
Latitude,
Longitude,
Current,
Previous,
Destination
)
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT Name, Time, Area, Latitude, Longitude, Current, Previous, Destination) AS tmp
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT  Name, Latitude, Longitude, Time FROM
        locations
        WHERE Name = 'Ocean' AND Latitude = '145.717' AND Longitude = '-16.6365' AND Time = '2014-04-23 13:45')

Comment: I believe this is being triggered by the SELECT as TMP line. If I remove Name from this line, I receive the error on Time:

    SELECT Time, Area, Latitude, Longitude, Current, Previous, Destination) AS tmp

When I remove AS tmp, I receive the error:

#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Yes it was missing alias and sub query is not structured well. I have added a query which should work.

Comment: When I run this, it seems to add an endless loop of rows. I ended up with over 1.7 million rows added to my table. *By the way, thank you very much for the help you're providing me

Comment: I guess thats because you are adding to the same table by selecting data from the same table. Usually this kind of operation is useful while you want to add data from one table to another.

Comment: I don't understand, I am trying to add new data to my table. My variables are coming from a separate location (not being pulled from this table)

Comment: if you look at the query you can see what it does, it tries to find the record from the same table where some condition is not fulfilled and then add into the same table, so its finding a lot of record which are not satified with the condition and adding them back to the same table.

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase my question. I want to enter new data into my MYSQL database, but before I do so, I need to check that it doesn't exist.

Comment: I have found the solution to what I was trying to accomplish in the following manner:

    INSERT INTO locations (`Name`, `Area`, `Latitude`, `Longitude`, `Current`, `Previous`, `Destination`, `Time`)
    SELECT a.Name, a.Area, a.Latitude, a.Longitude, a.Current, a.Previous, a.Destination, a.Time FROM (
     SELECT '$Name' Name, '$area' Area, '$latitude' Latitude, '$longitude' Longitude, '$currentport' Current, '$previousport' Previous, '$destination' Destination, '$time' Time) a
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM locations WHERE `Name`= '$Name' AND `Longitude` = '$longitude');

Comment: This successfully checks my variables against the database and inserts a record if there are changes in the selected variables. If you would like to add this answer, I will accept it. Thank you!

Comment: ok so intead of select you are doing select data from the alias table before inserting it...good.

Comment: Thanks again for sticking with me through this!